# In powershell how can I list AD computer properties vertically in gridview?

Tags: powershell, gridview

The following code produces a table with the properties listed horizontally:

```
("server1","server2") | %{ Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties * } |Out-GridView
```

How do I instead list the properties vertically like this:

```
DisplayName     server1     server2
DNSHostName     server1.domain  server2.domain
Enabled         true        false
IPv4Address     1.2.3.4     1.2.3.5
...
```

Bonus question:  How do I list all 88 AD computer object properties? In the command above only a subset is displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this:

```
$ComputerNames = "server1","server2"

$Computers = $Computernames | Get-ADComputer -Properties * 
$GridObjects = 
foreach ($Property in $Computers[0].psobject.properties.name)
 {
   $Hash = [ordered]@{Property=$Property}
    foreach ($Computer in $Computers) 
     {$Hash[$Computer.Name] = $Computer.$Property}

  [PSCustomObject]$Hash
 }   

 $GridObjects | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know as this pertains to 'out-gridview' you cannot sort properties of a record vertially, as they belong to that record, and need to be on the same line.  Why are you using out-gridview, if you use this command inside ISE, it will list them verically, and show you ALL fields.

```
($server1,$server2) | %{Get-ADComputer $_ -Properties *}
```

Comment: I'd like to compare the values side-by-side.  The output of that snippet lists the server sequentially.